# How to pass controller name throught query string Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, url-rewriting, codeigniter-url

How to pass when controller name is inside folder.

```
index.php?c=welcome
```

I tried this `index.php?c=A/welcome` which is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config file has this:

```
$config['controller_trigger']   = 'c';
$config['function_trigger']     = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger']    = 'd';
```

It says: `"// experimental not currently in use"`

I looked at the Router class that handles this and it looks like it uses the value passed in ?d= to set the directory...you might want to try that.

It would look like

```
index.php?d=A&c=welcome
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the folder name before controller and append the variables after it. like

- index.php / foldername / controllerName / functionName

NOTE:
Use of "index.php" is mostly depends on you as you have used them with others.

Comment: brother i know how to pass like this..i am trying to achieve this from query string index.php?c=a/name